# Is it possible to directly send data through TCP connection?

Tags: tcp

I have been using GET and POST methods to communicate with my web server, but now I just need to send data only and receive, as well.

For instance I want to send "abcd" string only.

Comment: This question is not very clear, I hope I have answered it as you desire below but please consider rewording the questions to be clearer.

Comment: Welcome to NE, we hope you will both contribute to and learn from this community. You could improve your question by editing it to add more details. You may find our [Question Checklist](http://meta.networkengineering.stackexchange.com/q/292/33) helpful when editing your question. For example: providing more context into what you are actually trying to do.

Answer (score 3):

It is absolutely possible to communicate through a TCP connection, and as jwbensley mentioned, Scapy is an excellent tool for packet manipulation.  However, in your instance, I would stick with something like [netcat](http://nc110.sourceforge.net/). Netcat is a low overhead tool that allows you to read/write data over the network.

A simple implementation of a TCP connection might look a lot like this.

```
Zgrkpnr@server:~$ netcat -l 4444

Zgrkpnr@client:~$ netcat server_ip 4444
```

More examples can be found over at [The Geek Stuff](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/04/nc-command-examples/).

Comment: +1 form me, yes nc is a much more strait forward program to recommend here as I don't think the OP isn't super clued up on packet crafting. NC is a great tool good idea.

Answer (score 2):

In answer to the question `Is it possible to directly send data through TCP connection?` - The answer is Yes.

If you wanted to expand and that and enquire as to how to do that, you could write a program yourself or use a packet crafter like [Scapy](http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/) or [Ostianto](https://code.google.com/p/ostinato/).

Obviously though, if you are going to step out of the usual behaviour of the 7 layer OSI model know that the communications you desire might not strictly work depending on how the network stack on the operating systems behaves.

If you are considering with a web server on TCP port 80 without using the proceedures defined within the HTTP protocol your results might not be what you expect. Keep in mind that a standard web server will be expecting communication that is adhearing to the rules of HTTP conversations.

Comment: How about SignalR? Do you have any knowledge about it? Is it capable of communication without HTTP protocol?

Comment: That is a different question and also not on topic here at NE, it's better asked at StackOverflow or somewhere similar. To the best of my knowledge SingalIR is running over HTTP.

Comment: +1 Scapy might have a little more of a learning curve than he's asking for, but it's certainly a viable tool for the job.

Answer (score -1):

<del>If you simply want to send datagrams, [jQuery AJAX](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/) should work fine?</del> (AJAX uses HTTP)

[Raw sockets](https://www.npmjs.com/package/raw-socket) on top of node.js.

If you want to develop something:
I use [node.js](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Node.js).  You can craft anything you can imagine.  [Google Cloud Platform](https://cloud.google.com/), for example, offers a free 60-day trial of up to (30) VMs w pubic ip addresses that you can develop/test on.  Alternatively, you could get a $50 rasperry pi and network it (provided your ISP allows you to map/have a routable public IP).

[Here's an example](http://www.hacksparrow.com/node-js-udp-server-and-client-example.html) UDP server and client.  Hope that helps.